# How do you make a subview size to fit a view controller in a Xamarin iOS storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, autolayout

Attempting to use AutoLayout in an iOS Storyboard within Xamarin Studio.

I have a `ViewController` with a `UIWebView` inside it. I want the `UIWebView` to fit the size of the device, minus the tab bar on the bottom and the carrier/battery bar on top.

I do the following:

1. Verified AutoLayout is enabled on the storyboard.
2. Select the `UIWebView`, then on the Layout tab, `Fill Parent` for vertical and horizontal.
   [image: Fill Parent]
3. Add Recommended Constraints
4. It looks great for the current setting, but then I change back and forth from an iPhone 6 to an iPhone 6 plus and it is well outside the bounds I was looking for:
   [image: Changing Device Profile]

I have to be missing something painfully obvious that is causing the UIWebView to remain in its previous size.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because the layout is not re-calculated when you change screen sizes in the designer? Aka the view is orange?

Comment: Yeah, the actual device mirrors the storyboard display...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the frames, my guess is your constraints are correct, but you didn't update the constraints after you changed the view size.

In Xamarin Studio, you can do this by clicking "Update frames based on constraints", the button on the right:

[image]

Comment: No change after Update Frames... :/